# How to track an actor from the left of the screen?

Tags: gamesalad

How can I make the camera start tracking my actor starting from the left side of the screen; not when he reaches the middle?

As you can see, the tracking area is in the middle of the screen and I'm not able to move it so it can align with the actor in the far left of the screen, i.e when the actor starts moving I want the camera to start tracking him instantly and not wait till he reaches the middle.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The way I've done this in the past is to create an invisible actor and constrain it to to the actor's position + 50% of the screen width, and then track that invisible actor with the camera